# Get string of characters from a vector of strings where the resulting string is equivalent to the majority of the same chars in the nth pos in strings

Tags: c++

I'm reading from a file a series of strings, one for each line.
The strings all have the same length.

File looks like this:

```
010110011101
111110010100
010000100110
010010001001
010100100011
[...]

Result : 010110000111
```

I'll need to compare each 1st char of every string to obtain one single string at the end.
If the majority of the nth char in the strings is 1, the result string in that index will be 1, otherwise it's going to be 0 and so on.

For reference, the example I provided should return the value shown in the code block, as the majority of the chars in the first index of all strings is 0, the second one is 1 and so on.

I'm pretty new to C++ as I'm trying to move from Web Development to Software Development.
Also, I tought about making this with vectors, but maybe there is a better way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you show the result of your example input should be `010110000111` but it should actually be `010110000101` instead, because the 11th column has more `0`s than `1`s in it.

That being said, what you are asking for is simple.  Just put the strings into a `std::vector`, and then run a loop for each string index, running a second loop through the vector counting the number of `1`s and `0`s at the current string index, eg:

```cpp
vector<string> vec;
// fill vec as needed...

string result(12, '\0');
for(size_t i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    int digits[2]{};
    for(const auto &str : vec) {
        digits[str[i] - '0']++;
    }
    result[i] = (digits[1] > digits[0]) ? '1' : '0';
}

// use result as needed...
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/wI2jon)